# Entity class configuration in a Spring Java configuration

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-java-config

In a Spring Hibernate XML configuration, I have

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    // ...
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.abc.xyz.Foo</value>
            // ...
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
        // ....
        </props>
    </property>
    //..
</bean>
```

I know an equivalent of a Spring Java configuration is the following:
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource()).addAnnotatedClasses(Foo.class).buildSessionFactory();

My question is how to do the same if I don't use the LocalSessionFactoryBuilder class, but HibernateJpaVendorAdapter and LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following way:

```
    @Bean
    public AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.abc.xyz.Foo");
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistence());
        entityManagerFactory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out that I need to add the domain package, but not entity class as a part of PackagesToScan in LocalSessionFactoryBuilder class. There are a few way of configuration. It is hard for anyone new to this field.

Comment: @vic Good!-Please remember to accept the answer if it's working correctly :)